# Slidedown menu not lining up

Tags: jquery, css

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AwexR/13/) of what I have. For some reason, the list containing the dropdown elements keeps sliding down pushed all the way to the left, even with `float:none;` I'm not sure if this is something obvious I am just overlooking, or whats going on, but I'm fairly certain the issue is in my CSS.

Comment: why you need jQuery for this - http://jsfiddle.net/smGHg/

Comment: To get the slide effect, and I'm new to jquery, so I want to practice it. Also, your fiddle doesn't work. When you try to hover over the dropdown from the parent link, the dropdown disappears (unless the user is super fast with their mouse)

Comment: ah! ok. Yes the slide effect. However the fiddle does work. When you hover over the 2nd "links" the "link1, link2, link3" shows and similiarly when you hover over last "links" and the "link4, link5, link6" shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your CSS.  You are giving your `dropdown` class a `position: absolute;` but not defining the values.  Thus it shows up in the default `left: 0; top: 0;`.

Comment: but its contained in a within an `<li>`? Shouldn't it automatically line up because of where it is contained in html?

Comment: I don't understand why this (http://jsfiddle.net/L5u3U/) works, but what I'm trying to do now doesn't?

Comment: No, because your `<li>` is not given a position.  `position: absolute;` takes the first parent container that has `position: relative;` as its context.  Since none of your elements define a `position: relative;` the root element is used, in this case the `<ul>`.

Comment: well, I gave the parent `<li>` a float, as opposed to the link contained in the `<li>`, and that did it. Thanks!